# ¿Como puedo hacer scroll en la terminal Linux sin usar el mouse?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Estoy utilizando UBUNTU sin interfaz gráfica, y cuando abro un fichero que es muy extenso solo se ven las últimas líneas de abajo, y quisiera saber cómo hacer un scroll en vertical hacia arriba y abajo usando el teclado (combinación de teclas) ya que cuando uso Ubuntu sin interfaz gráfica no puedo usar el mouse.

Comment: 1. Eso no es _programación funcional_ (colocá el mouse encima de la etiqueta para saber a qué se refiere), así que eliminá esa etiqueta. 2. ¿Con qué editor estás abriendo el fichero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para Ubuntu sin interfaz grafica puedes usar 'Shift + Page up' para hacer scroll hacia arriba y 'Shift + Page down' para scroll hacia abajo.

Si quieres ir al inicio del contenido de la terminar puede funcionar tambien 'Ctrl + Shift + Home' y para ir a la ultima linea escrita 'Ctrl + Shift + End'

Espero y te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, si me funciono su ayuda